# C# list sort by two columns

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a C# custom object list that I need to sort by two different variables one is a boolean and the other is a string. I can sort by *either* of the criteria, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to combine them. The sort should be all of the boolean values first (CheckedIn) and then the last name for each of the values. Right now I use

```
result.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.CheckedIn.ToString(), y.CheckedIn.ToString()));
result.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.LastName, y.LastName));
```

But how can I combine then so that my results are like

```
CheckedIn-Name
No - Aames
No - Smith
Yes - Barnes
Yes - Peters
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
result.Sort((x,y) => x.CheckedIn==y.CheckedIn ? 
  string.Compare(x.LastName, y.LastName) : 
  (x.CheckedIn ? -1 : 1) );
```

Comment: I don't want to ask a very similar question - thus, what is the equivalent if you want to sort by a double and string type with .Sort?

Answer (score 46):

use linq.

if you have list L of objects of class

```
public class temp
{
public bool x;
public string y;
}
```

then use:

```
L.orderby(a=>a.x).thenby(a=>a.y);
```

you can chain it as far as you like.

Comment: In his case, it would be result.OrderBy(x => x.CheckedIn).ThenBy(x => x.LastName);

Comment: I think ThenBy() does not perform the sort on the object but returns a new sorted list, so it should be "result = result.OrderBy(x => x.CheckedIn).ThenBy(x => x.LastName);" EDIT: You might need a new variable because the result type is an IOrderedEnumerable object.

Comment: Edit 2: You can cast back to your variable with ToList() as shown in the answer from lahsrah. I should better read all first before commenting :)

Answer (score 22):

```
var sortResult = result.OrderBy(a => a.CheckedIn).ThenBy(a => a.LastName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a class that creates CSV files using `List<List<string>>` in a `_Records` variable. I needed way to sort it after the fact, and LINQ was no good.

This is what I created as a multi-sort by passing in the indexes of the columns I wanted to sort.

```
public void OrderBy(params int[] columnIndexes)
{
    _Records.Sort((x, y) =>
    {
        foreach (int i in columnIndexes)
        {
            int result = string.Compare(x[i], y[i]);
            if (result != 0)
                return result;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Usage would then be...

```
csv.OrderBy(1, 3, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method I wrote for sorting a list by any number of keys:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void SortBy<T>(this List<T> list, params Expression<Func<T, IComparable>>[] keys)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if(keys == null || !keys.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("Must have at least one key!");
        list.Sort((x, y) => (from selector in keys 
                             let xVal = selector.Compile()(x) 
                             let yVal = selector.Compile()(y) 
                             select xVal.CompareTo(yVal))
                             .FirstOrDefault(compared => compared != 0));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var List<Person> persons = GetPersons();
myList.SortBy(p => p.LastName, p => p.FirstName);
```

Note that this is roughly equivalent to: `myList = myList.OrderBy(p => p.LastName).ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something fast/dirty by doing this.. since both columns are text, just add them together to sort in one quick pass.

this.Project.Tasks.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare((x.Assignee + x.Task), (y.Assignee + y.Task)));

Answer (score 0):

[Comparison Chain in C#](https://github.com/sayedsaad07/ComparisonChain_In_C-.git)

Here's my comparison chain solution. It will take care of aggregating all comparer classes you are interested in sorting by. the builder pattern makes it easy to provide columns to sort by and get a sorted list in return.